# Insertar prefijo en una tabla antes de volcar con PHP

Tags: php

Hola tengo esta variable `$filesop[1]` con un contenido

y necesito insertar un prefijo llamado **ESC** y despues el contenido de la variable `$filesop[1]`

Tengo este comando:

```
$referencia_pro = 'ESC';
$referencia = ($referencia_pro,$filesop[1]);
```

Mi duda es que colocar aqui:

```
$referencia = ($referencia_pro,$filesop[1]);
```

Para que pinte todo como un solo contenido.

**Ejemplo:**

```
$referencia_pro = 'ESC';
$filesop[1] = 1234
```

Resultado Final debe ser: **ESC1234**

> Me da error de: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','

Comment: Te da error por que en PHP, el símbolo para concatenar es el punto `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En php para **concatenar** (unir) dos Strings existen dos operadores...

> . (punto u operador de concatenación)

Este te permite unir dos cadenas de texto, colocar una al lado de la otra siguiendo el orden natural en el que han sido posicionadas. Esto puedo ocurrir con variables o cadenas.

**Ejemplo .1 Uso con variables.**

```
echo $var1.$var2;
```

**Ejemplo .2 Uso sobre cadenas.**

```
echo "Hola"."Mundo";
```

> .= (punto e igual u operador de asignacion sobre concatenación)

Este añade al argumento del lado izquierdo el del lado derecho.

**Ejemplo**

```
echo $var1 .= $var2;
```

Answer (score 3):

Para concatenar en `PHP` usa el punto `(.)`

Por ejemplo:

```
$total = $uno . $dos;
```